# Is it possible to catch errors within an iframe with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the lightwidget to include instagram posts to my website with an iframe.

Some people have Firefox settings / plugins to block posts from instagram, so they'll get the error: `GET https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/v/somepost net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

because the images wont load. Can I somehow catch that error?

I want to show some message instead and display: none; the iframe, so the user doesn't see an endless spinning wheel.

I tried to catch the error like this, but it didn't work:

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(event) { 
    alert('error')
})
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: you could always determine if they allow instagram by trying to load an image from instagram and checking if it loaded without issue

Comment: then using some global variable to determine if you should show IG etc